# How to calculate pH resulting from dissolving a salt in water?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, solutions, ph, theoretical-chemistry

The main question is how to calculate the changes in pH after dissolving a salt in water.

Suppose we dissolve 1 gram of magnesium carbonate (MgCO3) in 1 liter of Water. This will result in (approximately)

- 0.50 dGH
- 0.73 dKH
- 2.16 ppm Mg
- 7.84 ppm CO3

If we now add and dissolve 1 gram of calcium chloride (CaCl2.2H20) we get

- 0.39 dGH
- 0 dKH
- 2.73 ppm Ca
- 4.82 ppm Cl

(Assumptions: the water is pure distilled H20; the salt is fully dissolved; dissolution takes place at 20C and at sea-level (1 atm) pressure)

In total we will get dKH = 0.50 + 0.39, and dKH = 0.73 + 0.00

Since KH acts as a pH buffer due to its acid-neutralizing capacity, is it somehow possible to derive the change in pH from changes in KH and/or DH? If not, how can I calculate a change in pH from salt dissolution? Any background on how to do this would be welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry SE! MgCO3 solubility is 0.139 g/L so good luck in dissolving 1 g.  ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium_carbonate )

Comment: We have the policy which states that ‎you should explicitly show your thoughts, effort and attempts to understand underlying principles and solve the question.  It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, the  question may get closed and you may need to ask for  reopening when requirements are met.

As [Homework](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) is considered literal homework, exams, self-study questions, puzzles, worked examples etc.

Comment: dKH cannot be bigger than dGH, as the former represents Ca+Mg as bicarbonates, i.e. temporary hardness, the latter total Ca+Mg.

Comment: btw your question can be reopened once you edit it